# nginx location proxy pass forwarding to root URL rather than subdirectory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx as a proxy, `example.com` is my outward-facing web server with SSL enabled I want traffic coming under `https://example.com/gibberish/` to be forwarded under `http://localhost:8080/gibberish/`,

eg.: `https://example.com/gibberish/gg` to `http://localhost:8080/gibberish/gg`

I have done the conf like following, it doesn't work am getting error 404, when I check logs it shows me the request is being forwarded to `localhost:8080/`instead of `localhost:8080/gibberish/`, do I have to use 'rewrite', if yes, can you help with that?

```
location  /gibberish/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/gibberish/
}
```